# Joining graphs with entity resolution

Tags: graph, graph-theory, data-science

This is my first stack overflow question.

What's a good way of joining two graphs together that have unclear entities as their nodes?

The reason why the entities are not clear may be due to typos or more complicated reasons like having attribute values "J. Smith" vs "John Smith". Is there some way to run entity resolution on the graphs together so that they can be merged?